# Log and exp problems.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

The question,
$$\ln 4 - 2\ln(x+1) = \ln e$$
Solve for $x$

Here is what I did:
$$\ln \frac {4}{(x+1)^2} = \ln e$$
Hence, 
$$\frac {4}{(x+1)^2} = e$$
Unable to move further.

Please note my textbook advances 2 possible answers $-3$ and $1$

Comment: This is just a quadratic equation, $e$ is a constant

Comment: $4/(x+1)^2 = e$ so $(x+1)^2 = 4/e$ so $x+1 = \pm 2/\sqrt{e}$ so $x = -1 \pm 2/\sqrt{e}$.  Except $ln (x+1) $ means x > 0 so $x = -1 + 2/\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: You are right. The solutions given are those for $4/ (x+1)^2 = 1$, i.e. for the original eq. $=0$ and not $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide by $e$ and multiply by $(x+1)^2$. Then expand the square:

$$x^2 + 2x + 1 = \frac{4}{e}$$

Hence

$$x^2 + 2x + 1 - \frac{4}{e} = 0$$

Second degree equation:

$$x_{1,\ 2} = \frac{-2\pm \sqrt{4 - 4\cdot\left(1 - \frac{4}{e}\right)}}{2} = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4 + \frac{16}{e}}}{2} = \frac{-2\pm \sqrt{\frac{16}{e}}}{2} = \frac{-2\pm 4\sqrt{e^{-1}}}{2} = $$
$$x_{1,\ 2} =  -1\pm 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{e}}$$

**Of Course**

One of the solutions is not valid since you need $(x+1)^2 > 0$

Answer (score 0):

From $\frac{4}{(x+1)^2} = e$, you can solve for $x$ normally:

$$\frac{4}{e} = (x+1)^2$$

$$\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{e}} = x+1$$

$$x = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{e}}-1$$

We see that $x = \frac{2}{\sqrt{e}}-1$ since the other solution would be invalid for $ln(x+1)$.

Comment: Remember the other solution!

Comment: Fixed - thanks!

Comment: The other solution is invalid (as the starting equation requires $x+1>0$.